# D3 V5 Word Wrapping in Circle

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm fairly new to D3 and made some progress, but this problem has completely stumped me.  I can't seem to get my text to fit inside circles.  I don't anything too fancy, I think just simple line breaks would even pass.

Here's my sample code to generate circles and text.

```
graph
.selectAll('circle')
.data(this.nodes)
.enter()
.append('circle')
.attr('r', 30)

graph
.selectAll('text')
.data(this.nodes)
.enter()
.append('text')
.attr('x', 0)
.attr('y', '.31em')
.attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
.text((d: Vertex) => d.name)
```

I have tried adding tspans but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: I recommend you search "svg text wrap" on google, there are many articles and questions on this subject with various solutions. There is no simple way to text wrap with SVG

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try to use [d3plus](https://d3plus.org/) plugin for D3, here is an example:

```js
// Wrap text in a rectangle.
  d3plus.textwrap()
    .container(d3.select("#rectWrap"))
    .draw();

  // Wrap text in a rectangle, and size the text to fit.
  d3plus.textwrap()
    .container(d3.select("#rectResize"))
    .resize(true)
    .draw();

  // Wrap text in a circle.
  d3plus.textwrap()
    .container(d3.select("#circleWrap"))
    .draw();

  // Wrap text in a circle, and size the text to fit.
  d3plus.textwrap()
    .container(d3.select("#circleResize"))
    .resize(true)
    .draw();
```

```css
svg {
  font-family: "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
  height: 425px;
  margin: 25px;
  width: 900px;
}

.type {
  fill: #888;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

.shape {
  fill: #eee;
  stroke: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="//d3plus.org/js/d3.js"></script>
<script src="//d3plus.org/js/d3plus.js"></script>

<svg>

  <!-- Text that will use the D3plus default wrapping. -->
  <text class="type" dy="15px" x="75px">Wrapped</text>

  <rect class="shape" height="150px" width="150px" y="50px"></rect>
  <text id="rectWrap" class="wrap" y="50px" font-size="12">
    Here is a long text string that SVG should wrap by default, but it does not.
  </text>

  <circle class="shape" r="75px" cx="75px" cy="300px"></circle>
  <text id="circleWrap" class="wrap" y="225px" x="0px" font-size="12">
    Here is a long text string that SVG should wrap by default, but it does not.
  </text>

  <!-- Text that D3plus will resize to fit the available space. -->
  <text class="type" dy="15px" x="275px">Resized</text>

  <rect class="shape" height="150px" width="150px" y="50px" x="200px"></rect>
  <text id="rectResize" class="wrap" y="50px" x="200px" font-size="12">
    Here is a long text string that SVG should wrap by default, but it does not.
  </text>

  <circle class="shape" r="75px" cx="275px" cy="300px"></circle>
  <text id="circleResize" class="wrap" y="225px" x="200px" font-size="12">
    Here is a long text string that SVG should wrap by default, but it does not.
  </text>

  <!-- For comparison, how SVG would display the text without D3plus. -->
  <text class="type" dy="15px" x="475px">Default Behavior</text>

  <rect class="shape" height="150px" width="150px" y="50px" x="400px"></rect>
  <text class="wrap" y="50px" x="400px" font-size="12">
    Here is a long text string that SVG should wrap by default, but it does not.
  </text>

  <circle class="shape" r="75px" cx="475px" cy="300px"></circle>
  <text class="wrap" y="225px" x="400px" font-size="12">
    Here is a long text string that SVG should wrap by default, but it does not.
  </text>

</svg>
```